# Database performance testing using Java client

Tags: java, database, jpa

I have a school project that requires me to do some Java clients that connect to diverse SQL databases and one NoSQL (MongoDB). 
For the SQL DB I've used JPA to make it easy on myself.

This is how I insert into the database using JPA.

```
EntityManager entityManager= ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction et = entityManager.getTransaction();
et.begin();
int index_flush = 1;
for(Iterator<Book> it = bookList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    book = it.next();
    entityManager.persist(book);

    if((flush_index % 20) == 0) {
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
    }
    flush_index++;
}           
et.commit();
```

**My question is : Where do I measure the execution time?** 
  What I know is that `entityManager.persist` and `entityManager.flush` does not actually communicate with the Database. The changes on DB can be only seen when entity transaction commit is called. 
  Do I only need to measure the time it takes to do that commit ?

Thanks in advance! If I'm not clear in my explanation please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Flush DOES execute the SQL statements. So you can measure the time that flush takes.

Comment: Interesting. I see no changes in the Database until transaction commit. Do I need to set some parameters for this ?

Comment: @Alexandru the changes are only visible within the transaction you flush itself, they're not committed for the rest of the world to see until the transaction is (drumroll) - committed.

Answer (score 0):

It might be bacause they are in different transaction.
1 Transaction initiated by the JPA
2 Transaction initiated by using the SQL developer/tool to check the rows in the database.

You might try setting the isolation level to read uncommitted in the sql developer/tool to view your uncommitted changes ,which are flushed but not committed.

Though setting the transaction level read uncommitted at application level is not recommended.

Comment: I guess you are referring to the reply left on Simon's comment .  I will try what you mentioned. Now knowing that flush actually does something in the DB i think the correct measurement will be to make a sum of the time it takes to flush and commit. Do you think that's correct ?

Comment: Yes,that what i was referring to.Yeah the cumulative time taken by flush and commit should provide the total time.It might be overkill but you can use a profiler to check how much time it will take

Comment: can you point me to an example or explication for profiler . I don't really what what It is. Thanks

Comment: You can download profiler like yourkit(it is although paid ,but gives you option to try it out).After installing the profiler If you are running your application on windows you can attach it to a running JVM and can capture the snapshot  and then can view it offline.The snapshot will give insight about the time taken by each query in sql and method call in java.Also, it will provide you details regarding the heap and ram utilization.You can perform load test and check the throughput of your application.Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will try that!